# PDF has broken links when saved with 'Optimize for Fast Web Save'

Tags: pdf, adobe, aspose, adobe-reader

When the user opens our PDF (created with Aspose) inline in a browser, all the links work. Also, a browser's Save As (right-click) produces the right PDF.

But when they try to save the inline locally-opened copy via File|Save As **from inside Adobe Reader**, some of our hyperlinks break.

- 1) The TOC (Table-of-Contents) links work;
- 2) Actual links on a page are broken.

We determined that this happens when **Preferences / Documents / "Save As Optimizes for Fast Web View" is checked**. Upon disabling it the full PDF with all hyperlinks work, both TOC and page links.

Is this a known issue or bug? We're using Adobe Reader XI.

Comment: Do not add a vote for "close" without explaining what the issue is.

Comment: I have tested scenario using latest release of Aspose.Pdf and the links created using following code are working fine (both in Save As option when viewing PDF inside browser or when using Save As feature from Adobe Reader). The problem might be related to PDF file which you are using. Can you please share your sample project and input file.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose

CodeFile link = https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdjjwxwa7po4pe0/codefile.txt?dl=0